# PostgreSQL Check constraint not picking up two conditions within the code

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I've run into an issue with adding a check constraint to one of my tables in my database. The check constraint's purpose is to make sure that times past 12:00 on a Wednesday cannot exist. This is what I've got:

```
alter table module_daytime
    add CONSTRAINT CHK_TimeWED CHECK (Time BETWEEN '9:00' AND '12:00' AND Day='Wednesday')
```

I have already added data that abides to this rule into the table, however, when I try to add it, it still says that a row in my table violates said rule. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? MySQL does not do anything with CHECK constraints. There will be no error message.

Comment: Please run the query `SELECT @@version;` and tell us what it says.

Comment: That is one of the things I hate about MySql: it dosen't even bother to raise an error when you create a check constraint, it simply ignores it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I dislike that about MySQL too, but since the OP says the definition of the CHECK constraint *did* cause an error, I think they are not using MySQL.

Comment: @bill you are probably right.

Comment: @ZoharPeled oops I'm using PostGreSQL

Comment: "oops" so fix the question. don't place such important into into just a comment. i.e. in future change the tags and headings for corrections of that sort.

Comment: is "Time" a timestamp? You will have to cast it to `time` if it is.

Comment: What is the **exact** error you get? **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue (see below). Can you try to reproduce your table and test data for JUST that constraint.

> ```
> create table module_daytime("time" time, day varchar(20) );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into module_daytime values ('12:00', 'Wednesday');
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from module_daytime;
> ```
>
> ```
> time     | day      
> :------- | :--------
> 12:00:00 | Wednesday
> ```

> ```
> alter table module_daytime
>     add CONSTRAINT CHK_TimeWED CHECK (Time BETWEEN '9:00' AND '12:00' AND Day='Wednesday');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into module_daytime values ('12:00', 'Wednesday');
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> insert into module_daytime values ('12:01', 'Wednesday');
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  new row for relation "module_daytime" violates check constraint "chk_timewed"
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (12:01:00, Wednesday).
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=de4c3a142d76182ea98d113d08dd39ee)*